# Scrapy crawl site including non-HTML items

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl an entire website, including images, CSS, JavaScript and external links. I've noticed that Scrapy's default `CrawlSpider` only processes HTML responses and ignores external links. So I tried overriding the method `_requests_to_follow` and removing the check at the beginning but that didn't work. I also tried using a method `process_request` to allow all requests but that failed too. Here's my code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=False,
                  process_request='process_request'),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        node = Node()
        node['location'] = response.url
        node['content_type'] = response.headers['Content-Type']
        yield node

        link = Link()
        link['source'] = response.request.headers['Referer']
        link['destination'] = response.url
        yield link

    def process_request(self, request):
        # Allow everything
        return request

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        # There used to be a check for Scrapy's HtmlResponse response here
        seen = set()
        for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [l for l in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response) if l not in seen]
            if links and rule.process_links:
                links = rule.process_links(links)
            for link in links:
                seen.add(link)
                r = Request(url=link.url, callback=self._response_downloaded)
                r.meta.update(rule=n, link_text=link.text)
                yield rule.process_request(r)
```

The idea is to build a graph of the domain, that's why my `parse_item` yields a `Node` object with the resource's location and type, and a `Link` object to keep track of the relations between nodes. External pages should have their node and link information retrieved but they shouldn't be crawled, of course.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: From what I understand, for this type of crawling, [`pyspider`](https://github.com/binux/pyspider) could be a better fit.

Comment: Looking at pyspider's documentation I'd much rather use Scrapy if it's possible...